# How to make svg behave as text?

Tags: animation, svg, fonts

I'm currently having trouble having consistent display of my animated svg file currently as text. Generated with [termtosvg](https://github.com/nbedos/termtosvg).

I have manually added my font and other customizations to include in the svg file (`src: url(data:font/woff2;base64)` Share Tech Mono)

The animation has an ascii art that consists of braille characters and is not consistent across different browsers. The braille characters have a background boxes which shows on other browsers. For example on Firefox desktop it shows the background while on Firefox mobile it does not. Some browsers (Chrome/Chromium Windows) do not have the braille background and skews the ascii art instead.

Link to animated svg: [kleo/pipboy-3000-boot/termtosvg_unzww9gs.svg](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kleo/pipboy-3000-boot/master/svg/termtosvg_unzww9gs.svg)

Hosted on Github pages: http://kleo.hak.dog/kleo/

I am uncertain if this is a trouble on my desktop browser's (Firefox and Chromium on Arch Linux) included fonts.

I have attempted to replace some of the ascii art's characters with svg paths instead using [google-font-to-svg-path](https://danmarshall.github.io/google-font-to-svg-path/) but it does not behave like the text I have replaced. It is positioned on the very top left of the svg screen instead.

I previously used this animation as a gif for my [Github profile](https://github.com/kleo) but it is quite heavy to load the page so I resorted to using svg instead.

Is there an alternative to which I could properly display the terminal animation ascii art?

Comment: Start by fixing `Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:font/woff2;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAFawA… (“default-src”).` (which you can't, GitHub doesn;t give you control over raw.github, so host it through the pages functionality instead. Otherwise there's no way to know what's really wrong). And then reduce your problem to a [mcve]: animation's not the problem here, so just show the code an SVG with a single static braille character that's rendering wrong.

Comment: I get the same console error on Firefox desktop. But it also shows properly without any console errors on Safari desktop. MacOS Chrome shows the braille background without the CSP console error.

Comment: I also attempted to use `?sanitize=true` on my svg url. Still with the same result.

Comment: yes, because github does not allow hosting on the raw.github domain, that putely exists to show (unsurprisingly) plain text hosted with a text mime type and locked down CSP: you need to put in on a real host (e.g. github pages, or some other real hosting solution). Just go to your github repo's settings, go the "pages" section and turn on your kleo.github.io/your-project-name-here functionality.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no satisfying answer to your question. Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans already nailed your best options – fix the CORS/mime-type issues. SVG text-like behavior? In HTML sure! In SVG - no way as we can't place geometry elements within a native svg text element (e.g. in a `<tspan>`). Font-to-path relies on opentype.js for parsing and converting strings in a certain font as hardcoded svg data.  Fontkit is an alternative with some more advanced features. However, none of these libraries include a full fledged layout/text-compositing engine.

Comment: Even if the aforementioned libraries provided a way to convert complex text layouts to svg `<path>` elements: your animation would be huge in filesize. Although SVG's ability to provide self-contained animations is appealing - it's text capabilities are abysmal (e.g no multyline text).

Comment: I have attempted to host the svg on Github pages @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans still the same result. Different svg font behaviors across browsers.

Comment: Then remember to update your post, because it's still pointing to the raw.github location, which we already know can't work the way SVG is supposed to.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll keep the animation as is for now.